# How to call imaginary number "i" in an equation in C++?

Tags: c++, differential-equations, complex-numbers

I want to solve the differential equation,

```
idy/dx=x
```

using Euler method in C++, but i am not able to put i(iota) in the front of the equation.
My code is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::complex_literals;
int main() {
    std::complex<double> z = 1i;
    std::complex<double> y[100];

    int j;
    float h = 0.1, x[100];
    y[0]    = 0.0;
    x[0]    = 0.0;

    for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
        y[j + 1] = y[j] + h * imag(z) * x[j];
        x[j + 1] = x[j] + h;
        cout << x[j] << "\t" << y[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
0   (0,0)
0.1 (0,0)
0.2 (0.01,0)
0.3 (0.03,0)
0.4 (0.06,0)
0.5 (0.1,0)
0.6 (0.15,0)
0.7 (0.21,0)
0.8 (0.28,0)
0.9 (0.36,0)
1   (0.45,0)
```

When i run this code, the solution comes out to be real numbers only, however, the actual solution to the above differential equation is imaginary. I want to ask, is there any way I can write this i(iota) in my equation in the code.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code and explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: what is `y[i+1]=y[i]+h*imag(z)*x[i]` supposed to be when `i` is the imaginary unit?

Comment: when i run this code ,the solution comes out to be real numbers only, however, the actual solution to the above differential equation is imaginary.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When you have a question about code you need to show us the code, a [mcve]. The three lines you revealed dont make sense on their own and depending on what other code one adds can have very different meaning.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i added all the required details, please check now

Comment: `x` and `y` are non-complex numbers. `float` is not `complex`

Comment: `imag(z)` is also not complex. Nothing in the calculation makes the result complex

Comment: I think you actaully meant `y[j+1]=y[j]+h*z*x[j];` because `imag(z)` is the imaginary part of `z`, the imaginary part of `1i` is `1`

Comment: x should be a non-complex number, and y should be complex, how should i define y to be complex

Comment: how did you declare `z` to be complex? Its the same for `y`

Comment: i also tried writing z instead of imag(z), it shows lots of errors.

Comment: @LakshitaJindal `std::complex<double> y[100];`

Comment: @john it works, thanks. but still my answers to y[x] are real

Comment: @LakshitaJindal You should update the question with your latest code.

Comment: @john updated, please check now

Comment: `imag(z)`  is not a complex number. In your caclulations there is no complex number

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag2

Comment: yes, but I dont know how should I write z such that it gives imaginary answers

Comment: @LakshitaJindal I don't understand the maths, but it seems `y[j + 1] = y[j] + h * imag(z) * x[j];` should be `y[j + 1] = y[j] + h * z * x[j];`

Comment: @john the last line doesn't run, it shows errors. Maybe we can't directly call z in the equation.

Comment: @LakshitaJindal What are the errors?

Comment: `z` is the complex number you want. `imag(z)` is not what you want

Comment: And surely `x` should be `complex` too?

Comment: Your equation is dy/dx = -ix ([wolframalpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=i*dy%2Fdx+%3D%3D+x) ) ; It's easy to implement quickly Euler method for that, you just need to deal with complex numbers all the way. To answer, the question would need to be reopened, but you can already look [at this example](https://godbolt.org/z/jcK6jb3hY).

Comment: I got an error due to mixing `float` and `double` based complex numbers. If I stay with `float` no errors https://godbolt.org/z/a739jq94s

Comment: @user207421 x is real

Comment: You are also mixing `float` and `double`. Be consistent, pick one or the other. That might be the actual problem.

Comment: *Of course* `x` is real *in your current code*, but *in your current code* you are expecting a complex result, *in* `x`, which surely should therefore be complex?

Comment: @user207421 I suppose its a funtion R -> C, from real numbers to complex numbers. `x` is `double`, `y` is `std::complex<double>`